# I am using always the await keyword, but I get an error that says that the previous operation didn't complete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, async-await

I have this code:

```
private async void reasignarPiezasReservadas(DbContext paramDbContext)
{
    try
    {
        string miStrTsql = "select...";
        await paramDbContext.MyType.SqlQuery(miStrTsql).ToListAsync();

        miStrTsql = "Select...";
        await paramDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(miStrTsql);
    }
}
```

With this code I get the erro: {"A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."}

I am using the await in the two queries.

If in the first query I use ToList() instead of ToListAsync(), then I don't get the problem.

But why am I getting the error if I am using await in all cases?

Thanks.

Comment: The method body with `await`s is ok. It's more interesting how do you use (call) the method - it can be noticed that (1) the method is `async void` and (2) `DbContext` is passed externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the method definition from **async void** to **async Task**. Also its important that you add an **await** on the method call.